# Implementing search using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, search

Hello i am trying to implement a search functionality for my school project site. The idea of the site is a beer site eCommerce. I want to have a search where i can type some text and get the products from the database that include the input text in their name.

Currently what i am doing is **search.php:**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__."/connect.php";

var_dump($_POST['txt']);

 $text = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['txt']));

  $getName = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM products WHERE name LIKE concat('%', :name, '%') ");

  $getName->execute(array('name' => $text));

  while ($names = $getName->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)){
      echo '<div>' .$names["name"]. '</div>';
  };
  ?>
```

And the **search.js** file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#search_id').on('keyup', function (e) {
        $('#main_container').hide();
        let text = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'search.php',
            data: 'txt=' + text,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#container_search').html(data).show();
            }

        })

    })

    });
```

Currently when I type something in the search bar i get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: txt in C:\xampp\htdocs\BeerShop\search.php on
>   line 4 NULL
>
> Notice: Undefined index: txt in C:\xampp\htdocs\BeerShop\search.php on
>   line 6 asd (or the text i have entered).

Comment: You send it as `GET`. But look for `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem in search.php i was using $_POST while i was sending a GET method.